# Git is using Unix line endings on Windows despite explicit .gitattributes?

Tags: git

I am in a situation where with the settings below on my machine all text files in the working copy have Windows CRLF line endings (expectation), but one of my colleagues and the build box (both running Windows) have UNIX LF line endings. That's even after a fresh clone of the repository. All settings are identical and listed below. Even `*.txt` files which are specified to be `text eol=crlf` are checked out with LF.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

File attributes:

```
$ git check-attr --all XXX.cs
XXX.cs: diff: csharp
XXX.cs: text: set
```

Various settings:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.9.4.msysgit.0

$ git config --get core.eol

$ git config --get core.autocrlf
false

$ git config --global --get core.eol

$ git config --global --get core.autocrlf
false
```

The `.gitattributes` file:

```
* text=auto
*.txt eol=crlf
*.cs text diff=csharp
*.csproj text merge=union 
*.sln text merge=union 
*.proj text
*.config text
*.bat text
*.xml text
*.xsd text
*.ps1 text
*.Targets text
*.js text
*.css text
*.map text
*.html text
```

Comment: Just to be sure, do `git check-attr --all path/to/some/file/that/gets/bad/eols`

Comment: `$ git check-attr --all xxx.cs`
`xxx.cs: diff: csharp`
`xxx.cs: text: set`

Comment: @jthill The above output is the same on both machines. Does that help to answer the question?

Comment: For me, I'm afraid it's only by closing off one possibility. I don't have a Windows handy, maybe someone else can investigate or is just more intimately familiar with how git's eol handling behaves on msysgit.